# Setting the type of a NetBeans Module

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I have been developing a couple of NetBeans modules in parallel using the NetBeans IDE.  Yesterday (Dec. 12, 2012) the IDE updated and now I can not get any of them to manifest when I run the platform.  The platform loads up with no errors but my modules do not appear.  If I attempt to explicitly enable them I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not all requested modules can be enabled: [StandardModule:com.foo jarFile: D:\bar.jar]
at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1024)
```

I see that the module.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nbm>
    <!--
    <moduleType>autoload</moduleType>
    <codeNameBase>com.foo/1</codeNameBase>
    <licenseName>Apache License, Version 2.0</licenseName>
    <licenseFile>license.txt</licenseFile>
    -->
</nbm>
```

This is all auto-generated and it looks to be commented out, but it looks like it was attempting to set the module as an autoload module.  This is odd because it looks to me like the module is behaving as an autoload module.

So my question, which seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to figure out, how do I explicitly define the type of a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that problem may be between module dependencies.

1. Open your module project
2. Remove all module dependencies
3. Check your selected NB platform (or change)
4. Add all your module dependencies
5. Clean and build and install your module again

Comment: Our problem was actually slightly more environment specific than this, but this was the root of the problem.  For those who are interested, the real problem had to with how NetBeans adds module dependencies to Maven poms.  It can be guilty of making too many assumptions about version numbers, which was the problem in our case.